# Lotus Notes - Difference between the actual element and the element before from a list

Tags: list, view, lotus-notes

My form contains a numeric field called: `txt_number`, it is computed and it is the sum of two editable numeric fields: `txt_no1` and `txt_no2`.

All the `txt_number` fields are stored in a view ( to be able to get the element before) , in this way:

```
@Unique ( @DbLookup( "" : "NoCache" ; @DbName ; "vwTest" ; field1+field2 ; 2 ));
```

"vwTest" has 2 columns: the first is categorized ( field1+field2 ) and the second one has `txt_number` as its default column value.

So, the list from my topic question is `"vwTest"` containing all the `txt_number` values in the 2nd column.

Let say the first doc saved will have `txt_number = 5`. When a new doc. is created, and txt_no1 and txt_no2 are calculated , we get `txt_number = 10` .

The form has a computed field called `txt_diff` where I want to obtain the difference between the last txt_number and the actual one.( `10 - 5 = 5` )

So, if then it will be another new form with `txt_number = 50` => `txt_diff` ( on this new created doc ) should be `50-10 = 40.`

`vwTest`: field1+field2 | txt_number

- List item

  ```
                |   1   ( => on this doc, `txt_diff = 1` )
                |   10  ( => on this doc, `txt_diff = 9` )
                |   23  ( => on this doc, `txt_diff = 13`)
     .......................
  ```

Please , I need your help. Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think this is very confusing.  You are saying two different things: "txt_number... is computed and it is the sum of two editable numeric fields" and "The txt_number field si taken from a view, in this way:".  It obviously can't be both!  More confusion: what are field1 and field2?  You use them in your @DbLookup, but you don't mention them anywhere else in your question.  (And BTW: for most Notes developers, the prefix "txt_" is used for text fields, not number fields. This also makes your question confusing.)

Comment: I edited my question, hope to be clear. Both field1 and field2 are two editable fields on the form.

Answer (score 0):

It still some confusing but, if I understand you, you need to calculate txt_diff using that view as reference.

In that case, you can put some code in event QueryRecalc or QuerySave to do the calculation. This is an example code:

(I'm coding by memory, so it can have some errors)

```
dim o_view as NotesView
dim o_nav as NotesViewNavigator
dim o_doc as NotesViewEntry

set o_view = o_current_db.GetView("view_categorized_by_field1_field2")
set o_nav = o_view.CreateViewNavFromCategory(field1+field2)
set o_doc = o_nav.GetlastDocument  '<== THIS IS YOUR DOCUMENT TO CALCULATE txt_diff

'Do something more
```

However, unless you need txt_diff in real time, you can create an agent to do the calculations every X minutes. Both solutions depends of what are you need in your app.

I hope this helps.